# django - ImportError

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

I just successfully shipped my code to the production server. You can check out here http://qlimp.com

It shows

```
ImportError at /
No module named try.urls

Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    No module named try.urls
Exception Location: /home/nirmal/project/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py in import_module, line 35
Python Executable:  /home/nirmal/project/bin/python
```

Actually my django project name in the developement server is **try**. Then I exported the code to the project **qlimp** in the production server. I successfully performed every changes need to be done and I don't know why it shows that `No module named try.urls`

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my production server. Could anyone guide me?

Thanks!

Comment: Too many "successfully" for something that is not working actually. Too few relevant information.

Comment: `try` is a Python keyword and not a good choice for a module name.

Comment: I can give the information you need.

Comment: @MarkLavin But I'm not getting any errors in try project on my computer. Also I think it will not link with the production server

Comment: @rnk I'm not saying it will solve your problem (hence a comment rather than an answer) I'm just saying it's not a good name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In settings.py, change

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'try.urls'
```

to

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'qlimp.urls'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so much a straight answer as a few things to check - I'd suggest (if you haven't already) that you grep the new project for the string "try.urls".  Looks to me like the sort of thing that might happen if you missed changing over a config file or something.  If you have the patience for it, you might even try grepping "try".  Also, make sure that you've done a make clean to clear out any references that may be in compiled code.